# Find similar items in two columns in Excel

Tags: excel, match

I want to know how can I do this in Excel.

Here is a sample

```
column A        column B      
-------------------------
1                  2
2                  5
3                  4
4                  1
5                  3
```

I want Excel to check column A and B, then if it finds any match, move them to another sheet.

So in another sheet, I should have a list with its data sorted in front of each other based on similar code.

[Click here to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hdQE.png)

thanks

Comment: It is unclear what exactly is a match? the same value in both column in one row? any value that exists in both columns? And what do you mean by _" based on similar code"_? an example of the desired output will be very helpful.

Comment: please check the image

Answer (score 0):

Use match()
Sheet2:

```
A1:
=A1

B1: 
=indirect("sheet1!B"&match(sheet1!A1,sheet1!B:B,0))
```

I have not tested it but A1 should give you the value of sheet1 A1 and B1 should give you the matched value (if it excists) of A1.

I can't test it as I'm laying in bed with my phone.

Because I'm at work I have to use Swedish formulas, but it's the same formula, it's only translated.
[image]

Comment: I would use INDEX instead of INDIRECT as INDEX is not volatile.  `INDEX(sheet1!B:B,match(sheet1!A1,sheet1!B:B,0))`

Comment: it doesn't works for me. I need two columns but it just gives me one column.please check the image.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, I look up (Blad,Passa) on google translate, but there was not a specific meaning related to them. would you please write the formula in english for me. Another thing is that I want the criteria be the code not the word. for example code number 1 or 2 and not the word pig or dog. Thanks

Comment: @leonmordad It is in english a few lines higher. See: `=indirect("sheet1!B"&match(sheet1!A1,sheet1!B:B,0))`. How about you post an image of your screen with this formula. And please, both sheets.

Comment: I upload another photo, in that, I explain everything.please see the photo. Thanks

Comment: @leonmordad maybe you need to go back to the very basics of Excel? What you have posted is exactly what my formula does, so maybe the problem is what you type in?

Comment: when I apply it, it asks me to open an excel file. I think something is wrong. anyway I think its not gonna works. I am gonna look for other ways. thank you.

Comment: @leonmordad it does work. You are doing something wrong. And you have not given me enough information to help you either. You keep giving me bullshit data instead of real data, and THAT is probably the problem. Or something makes them not match (spelling or ascii code), or the sheetnames is not correct. But again.. you have not given me enough information to help you, I tried 2 days ago to make you submit pictures of the problem but you gave me goats and dogs. And nowhere do I see the actual formula you use. IF this formula I gave you did not work my answer would have been downvoted by others

Comment: and/or others would have posted other answers with how to do it. But since none of that has happened, and the fact that the formula does work. Maybe... just maybe it's you that is doing something wrong?